# Images are not displaying while using IE Page send By email option

Tags: html, css, email

When I send Html page by email using IE Page send By email option, then image is not appearing in email. I include image using inline css

This is my html code

```
<div class="bg-image">
    <p class="head-1" ><font face="arial" size=4>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>APJ Corporate Affairs </b></font><p/>
    <p class="head-2" >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b><font face="arial">Q3 2015 Recognition Awards</b></font></p>
</div>
```

This is my css code

```
.bg-image
{
    background-image: url("https://www.aaa.com/content/dam/www/program/images/q1-2015- 
    newsletter-banner-copy.jpg") ; 
    position:relative;
    height: 150px; 
}
```

Comment: This is due to security reason. You should try with base64 inlined images in your CSS

Comment: can you please give me any example of this?

Comment: check out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207190/embedding-base64-images